# Let $M$ be an oriented compact $n$-manifold. If $M$ has two components, what is $H_n(M;\mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

Let $M$ be an oriented compact $n$-manifold. If $M$ has two components, what is $H_n(M;\mathbb{Z})$?

I think the answer to this is $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$.

*Proof:* We can split $M$ up into its components $M_1$ and $M_2$. Both $M_1$ and $M_2$ are open in $M$ and $M_1 \cap M_2 = \emptyset$ so $M = M_1 \sqcup M_2$. Then $H_n(M;\mathbb{Z}) = H_n(M_1;\mathbb{Z}) \oplus H_n(M_2;\mathbb{Z})$.

Since $M$ is compact one can show both $M_1$ and $M_2$ will be compact as well and you can obtain an orientation of $M_i$ for $i = 1, 2$, by defining $s : M_i \to \widetilde{M_i}$ by $s(x) = (x, \mu_x)$ where $\mu_x = \operatorname{pr}(\tau(x))$  and $\tau : M \to \widetilde{M}$ is the given orientation of $M$ and $\operatorname{pr} : \widetilde{M} \to \{\pm 1\}\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ is given by $(y, \mu_y) \mapsto \mu_y$.

So since $M_i$ is an oriented compact $n$-manifold for $i = 1, 2$. We have that $H_n(M_i;\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}$ for $i = 1, 2$. Thus $H_n(M;\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$. $\square$

Are there any issues with this proof? I think I didn't really show that the section $s$ of the orientation covering is continuous, because I'm not sure how to show that $\operatorname{pr}$ is continuous. I mean we know  $\operatorname{pr}$ is a map to a discrete space so if $\operatorname{pr}^{-1}(-1)$ and $\operatorname{pr}^{-1}(1)$ are open then I'd be done, but I'm not sure how to see that.

Comment: Which definition of orientation do you use?